# Open file for Appending with is new indication

Tags: c#, .net

I need to append data to a file, but if the file does not exist I need to add a header before appending.

If I open the file with `FileMode.Append`, I cannot see a way to work out if the file is new or not.

If I open the file with

```
FileStream file;
boolean isNew;
try
{
    file = File.Open(path, FileMode.CreateNew);
    isNew = true;
} 
catch (IOException ex)
{
    file = File.Open(path, FileMode.Append);
    isNew = false;
}
```

I run into the risk of another process deleting the file between the the 2 open calls and not detecting the creation of the new file.

What is the recommended way of opening for appending and detecing if create or append?

Comment: Check if file exists. If exists, append. If not, create

Comment: Can you not use [File.AppendText(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.file.appendtext(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: No, need to append binary data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this do what you need?

```
try
{
    var file = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

    if (file.Length == 0)
    {
        // do header stuff
    }

    // do the rest
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    // handle io ex.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
     file = File.Open(path, FileMode.CreateNew);
     isNew = true;
     return;    
}
// otherwise append to existing file
file = File.Open(path, FileMode.Append);
isNew = false;
```

Comment: The problem with this is something could create the file between your `File.Exists(path)` and the point where you create it.  If you do it like I did in my answer, it can't happen because the file is locked once it's created and/or opened.  Also, if the file *does not* exist, this will try to open the file twice because the second `File.Open` is not in an `else` block.

Comment: @rory.ap - you missed the return at the end of the if block. Your solution is better though for the reasons you give.

Comment: @PaulF -- ahh yes, I did miss that.  Thanks.